# HTML remove url variables, NO PHP or JS solution

Tags: html, url, urlvariables

My site uses both PHP and the JS AJAX so I'm fairly familiar with them both, and I don't want a solution that includes them. I have this page structure where all my users stay on just one landing php page, which then fetches the right content depending on the URL's p variable.

```
http://www.example.com/?p=about
http://www.example.com/?p=aMap-anothermap-evenAnothermap-lastelyTheFile
```

This page structure works great for me except that I don't know the right way to make a link that just removes the whole `?p=home`. Because I want my home/start page to be variable free. I want it to be

```
http://www.example.com/
```

rather than

```
http://www.example.com/?p=home
```

Now I could just make the link

```
http://www.example.com/?
```

And then just remove the `?` with the JS `pushState()`, but that would look pretty silly and would only work for JS users.

Let's say i would want to the do the above example with just the `?` then I could create a link like this.

```
<a href="?">Link</a>
<script src="SomeCoolPushStateScript"></script>
```

And I know from experience that this doesn't even work:

```
<a href="">Link</a>
```

So here comes the question: How do I remove the `?variable=something` part of an URL when using an HTML `href`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path `./` should do the trick.

```
<a href="./">Link</a>
```

If you want to preserve the main script name, like `index.php`, you will have to include that name.

```
<a href="index.php">Link</a>
```

Alternately, you could dynamically generate domain-relative or absolute URL's with PHP.

Comment: For the OP's specific question, I think `href="/"` and even `href="www.example.com/"` could work as well.

Comment: @Andrew You would need to add `//`, `http://`, or `https://` for the second one, but yes, assuming it is at the root of the site.

Comment: The `<a href="./">Link</a>` did it for me, Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use querystrings.

```
<a href="/">Link</a>
```

would go to example.com's root.

I don't recommend using `"./"`. This would do what you want if the user is on a page that is in the root directory of your website (e.g. `http://www.example.com/page.html`). However, this would not work if they were on a page in a subdirectory. E.g. if the user's on `http://www.example.com/hello/page.html`, it would just link to `http://www.example.com/hello/`.

Using `"/"` makes sure the user goes to the root of your website.

Comment: Oh okay, I tried it and it didn't work but that's probably because my website is not currently in the root of my apache test server.

Comment: Is the ?variable=value extension on the URL called a querystring?

Comment: @JohanSundman I'll answer for Punit and say yes, that is a query string.